# Deploying Django on IIS and ngrok

Tags: django, deployment, ngrok, pyngrok

I am trying to deploy Django on local host and "tunnel" using ngrok. The ngrok works but the IIS (Internet Information Manager) gives 500 Error `<handler> scriptProcessor could not be found in <fastCGI> application configuration`. Reference into fastcgi shows that this feature is deprecated but what is the replacement for serving Django using local server and ngrok. I also pip installed pyngrok. Can you suggest a clear solution?

Comment: The pyngrok docs provide a working Django example: https://pyngrok.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integrations.html#django

Comment: That pyngrok setting didn't work for me. I am getting 500 Error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FastCGI was deprecated in Django 6+ years ago, [their docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/fastcgi/) say WSGI is the preferred alternative, and they provide a tutorial for [types of WSGI deployments](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/deployment/wsgi/) to get you started.

But you wouldn't use `ngrok` in this case, you'd serve it up with something like `nginx` or `apache` using a `wsgi` mod (also shown in their tutorial). Where you'd use `ngrok` is in development with [Django's built-in dev server](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/intro/tutorial01/#the-development-server), and that's the [full example provided in `pyngrok`'s documentation](https://pyngrok.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integrations.html#django).

Usually I'd provide actual sample code here, but what you're asking about are full end-to-end solutions, which is why I'm providing links. Without the full context and examples of what you've built, it's hard to tell you where it's going wrong—hard to provide specific solutions without specific examples of the problem. But these tutorials tutorials are for exactly what you're doing, so hopefully they can help you debug your own solution.

Comment: Do any of ngnix or Apache work with ngrok or alternatives to deploying a local development server?

Comment: Sure, `ngrok` is just generating a public URL that forwards to the local port you give it. That local port could be Django's dev server (8000 by default), or Apache or nginx (whatever port you set them up for), or something else completely like MySQL. If you don't want to mess with DNS or port forwarding on your router, using `ngrok` to forward to any server will work. I suggested Django's dev server simply because it requires zero setup compared to production-grade servers like nginx or Apache, but any will work.